# Sharepoint 2010 public facing site - do i need the ribbon?

Tags: 2010, publishing-site, publishing-page, publishing, public-website

I am implementing a custom design using the Zurb Foundation library. If I don't include the ribbon on the front end will the content author be able to edit content pages using SP Designer?

Answer (score 3):

you can add security trimmed on custom masterpage which only an authorised user will be able see the ribbon

```
1) Open your SharePoint master page
2) Locate this line:
   <div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle">
3) Change it to:
   <div id="s4-ribbonrow" class="s4-pr s4-ribbonrowhidetitle" style="display:none">


4) Now find the end of the “s4-ribbonrow” tag and add following
block right after it:

 <Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl2" runat="server" PermissionsString="AddAndCustomizePages">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "block";
        </script>
    </Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>


5) Save the new master page and publish it.
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zwsong/archive/2010/04/29/how-to-hide-ribbon-from-users-without-edit-page-privilege.aspx